# Escape `^@` in a variable

Tags: string-manipulation

Goal: print git diffs of pwd in a popup

```
let diff = system('git diff')
call popup_create(diff, {})
```

Problem: It prints `^@`([I've got to know that is newline chars](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/26.html#literal-strings)):

```sh
diff --git a/.config/fish/config.fish b/.config/fish/config.fish^@deleted file mode 100644^@...(ellipsis)
```

How could I escape the newline chars in the variable `diff`?

I tried substitute and it does not work:

```
let diff = system('git diff')
let diff = substitute(diff, '^@', '\n', 'g')
call popup_create(diff, {})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's documented, but if I see `^@` in the output because of newlines, what I'd do is see if a list of strings is allowed instead, and if so, the split the string on newline and pass that list instead:

```
:call popup_create(split(diff, "\n"), {})
```

It seems [`popup_create()`](https://vimhelp.org/popup.txt.html?#popup_create%28%29) does support a list of strings, so I'd expect this to then show the output the way you expect to see it.

Comment: Also see `systemlist()`

Comment: I second the `systemlist()` approach